# Как удалить все содержимое каталога?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

есть скрипт который должен удалить все содержимое в указанном каталоге

```
os.remove("".join(glob.glob("/opt/lammp/htdocs/site/*")))
```

если в каталоге **site** только файлы то все работает, если имеется хоть один каталог, то ошибка.
Как удалять все содержимое в указанном каталоге?

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления папки и вложенных в нее файлов и папок есть функция [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

Пример:

```
import shutil

shutil.rmtree('<путь к папке>')
```

*Если есть необходимость оставить пустую папку, то после [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) можно создать папку, но это костыль.* Тогда, другой вариант перебор содержимого и использование разных методов для удаления файлов и папок

Удаление содержимого папки без удаления папки (используя `shutil` и `pathlib`):

```
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import rmtree


for path in Path('<путь к папке>').glob('*'):
    if path.is_dir():
        rmtree(path)
    else:
        path.unlink()
```

Вместо метода `glob` можно использовать `iterdir`:

```
for path in Path('<путь к папке>').iterdir():
```

Comment: как оставить саму папку site?

Comment: @Юрий, хотите пустую папку оставить? Создайте ее [os.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) или [Path.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir), это самое простое. Либо, используйте перебор папок/файлов в вашей папке и для файлов вызывайте [os.remove](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) или [Path.unlink](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink), а для папок shutil.rmtree

Comment: это костыль, разве нет способа удалить содержимое папки не удаляя ее?

Comment: @Юрий, ну, нет метода удаления только содержимого папки. Способ удалить содержимое папки не удаляя я выше описал

Comment: @Юрий, добавил пример в ответ. Для удобства использования, оберните в функцию